# slideToggle hidden height not zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, slidetoggle

I'm currently grabbing #rightDesc's height in jQuery and using it to decide #rightHistory's height, both of which are divs.

```
$('#rightHistory').height($('#rightMiddleCenter').innerHeight() - $('#rightDesc').outerHeight() - $('#rightDescToggle').outerHeight());
```

The layout is below:

```
<div id="rightMiddleCenter">
    <div id="rightDesc">
    </div>
    <div id="rightDescToggle">
        Toggle Descriptions
    </div>
    <div id="rightHistory">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#rightMiddleCenter{
float:left;
height:100%;
width:260px;
}
#rightDesc{
padding:0 0 10px;
}
#rightDescToggle{
padding:5px 5px 5px 0;
cursor:pointer;
}
#rightHistory{
}
```

I've now decided to make #rightDesc toggleable with slideToggle, but when it's hidden jQuery still returns its full height. This results in #rightHistory's height not changing and not taking up the amount of space it should.
Can anyone suggest a solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a css too? I'm fumbling around here.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`way of hiding an element, the height and width of the element aren't changed, it just ain't visible.

edit:
I suggest using custom data attributes for your specific action and use those for your height-width usage. Or just build your calculation a bit different and check if an element is visible or not, that way substituting the height and width with 0.

Comment: When the element is toggled away, it is given a style of `display: none` eg: `<div id="rightDesc" style="display: none;">`

Comment: As I just found out, the height and width of an element are indeed still there, even when the element is on `display:none` and out of the DOM. It only shows 0 if the parent element is also set to `display:none`. You could fix this by using your own custom data attributes.